# Real time applications for counting numbers

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I am solving interesting questions which are quite frequently asked in programming interview like following:

1. Compute sum of digits in all numbers from 1 to n?
2. Compute number of perfect square between two given numbers?
3. Count numbers from 1 to n that have 4 as a digit?

I am wondering what are real time applications for above? Can any one please share there views.

Comment: I guess it is more to display way of original/combinatorial thinking, which can be further applied in real-life use cases. Real life application of discrete-mathematics does exist and very broad, even more so, most of the current data structures, algorithms arise from math.

Comment: Belongs to cs.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

I think these questions have multiple solutions. Question 1 and 3 are interesting because you can solve these problems without iteration in very clever ways, but also solve them using very long winded ways. As someone who does a lot of interviewing, I would want use this type of question to gauge the sophistication of the candidate at solving problems. On that basis I don't think giving you a clever answer to these question is going to be in your best interests to succeeding at interviews. How you tackle a problem and how far you can push the boundaries is what is likely being tested.